# Is it possible to run a command at boot time in windows 10?

Tags: windows, command-line, boot

I know that I can run a command after windows starts via command prompt but is there any way I can run a specific command before login ( at boot time ) which is automatic and repetitive at each boot?

I have seen some defrag tools like glary utilities, ultra defrag which can do defragmentation at boot time (at each boot) and I know that I can start windows in command prompt but I was wondering that is it possible for the user to at desired commands in boot time which will run at every new boot of the system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use Task Scheduler that comes with Windows.

Create a new task in there and then go to the triggers tab and change the "Begin the task" dropdown at the top to "At startup".

TIP: if it will be a long running task, that you don't want killed automatically after 3 days, go to the Settings tab and uncheck "Stop the task if it runs longer than 3 days"